# "for" loop not working as per need

Tags: batch-file

I have following code:

```
set b=Hello
set c=1
set d=5
for /l %%x in (1,1,%d%) do (set /a c=c+1 & set "a=%a%%b%%c%")
echo %a%
```

And for this, I wanted an output as:

```
Hello1Hello2Hello3Hello4Hello5
```

But instead, I get result as:

```
Hello1Hello1Hello1Hello1Hello1
```

Can anyone give me any idea on how can I do so?

Comment: The result from your code is just `Hello1`, _not_ the one you wrote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set b=Hello
set c=0
set d=5
for /l %%x in (1,1,%d%) do (set /a c=c+1 & set "a=!a!!b!!c!")
echo %a%
endlocal
```

The `!` variant of `%` will expand the variables at the time the code is *executed* whereas `%` expands when the code is *parsed.* And, since parsing happens on the entire statement (from `for` to the closing parenthesis), you'll get the original value only.

Note that you don't *need* delayed expansion for the invariant `b` but, once you've decided you need them, you may as well use them everywhere - they act more as you'd expect in most cases.

You'll notice I've also changed the initial value of `c` to get the output you stated that you wanted. As it was, you would get `2,3,4,5,6` rather than `1,2,3,4,5`.

Comment: _"Note that you don't_ need _delayed expansion for the invariant `b` but, once you've decided you need them, you may as well use them everywhere"_. I don't agree. There is not any reason to use delayed expansion on `b` in this case and the same point apply to _most cases_. The only difference in this case is that using `!b!` instead of `%b%` run slightly slower, but in other scenario doing this may even cause a wrong result. The use of delayed expansion always depends on the specific problem...

Comment: @Aacini, I actually gave the *reason* why I think it's a good idea at the end of that sentence, and the very existence of this question is an indication why. Most coders expect normal temporal behaviour from their code (well, other than non-procedural languages like Prolog) in that, if you change a data item then use it, it has the value you *changed* it to. I actually consider the behaviour of `%...%` to be the odd method and I suspect that's also why MS ended up finally adding delayed expansion.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "a="
Set "b=Hello"
Set "c=1"
Set "d=5"
For /L %%A In (%c%,1,%d%) Do Call Set "a=%%a%%%b%%%A"
If Defined a Echo %a%
Pause
```

Or alternatively:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "a="
Set "b=Hello"
Set "c=1"
Set "d=5"
For /L %%A In (1,%c%,%d%) Do Call Set "a=%%a%%%b%%%A"
If Defined a Echo %a%
Pause
```